# Creating a Box web app integration / callback that works only on folders?

Tags: box

I'm trying to create a web app integration for Box.com that is available from folders, like the "Send with Gmail" or "Send to Chatter" actions. It seems that integrations that we create from http://developers.box.com only work from files, and not from folders.

I did something similar to that in the past and I vaguely remember that the Box.com support team had to modify by action from their back-end to enable it; I compared integrations in my previous app with the new one I created and I see no visible difference in the configuration.

Has anyone done something similar recently and know the current procedure? I also tried opening a support case from their website and it hasn't been answered either.

Answer (score 2):

The Box support team got back to me on this one and changed the configuration of my web app integration. It's now working the way I expect. They confirmed that they're the only one capables of doing this configuration change - it's not possible to do it from developers.box.com. If anyone needs that - just open a support case on community.box.com and they'll do it for you.